# ASP.net: Cannot write to App_Data folder, Access is Denied

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload, file-permissions

Typical problem, but I've done everything I can possibly think of to get this to work. I set the NETWORK SERVICE and ASPNET accounts to FULL CONTROL on my PC. I'm using the built-in Cassini web server to test my application, with no luck. I even tried to make a folder outside of the APP_DATA folder, and is still says Access is Denied.

Anyone have any ideas?

CODE EXAMPLE:

```
  Dim uploadedFile As HttpPostedFile = Request.Files(0)
        Dim len As Integer = uploadedFile.ContentLength
        Dim fn As String = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName)
        Dim SaveLocation As String = Server.MapPath("~/Help")
        Dim MyStream As Stream = uploadedFile.InputStream
        Dim input(len) As Byte

        MyStream = uploadedFile.InputStream
        MyStream.Read(input, 0, len)

        Try

            Dim newFile As FileStream = New FileStream(SaveLocation, FileMode.Create)
            newFile.Write(input, 0, input.Length)
            newFile.Close()
            'Dim writer As Stream = New FileStream(SaveLocation, FileMode.Create)
            'writer.Read()
            'writer.Close()
            'uploadedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

Comment: are you sure the web server is running your site as the NETWORK SERVICE or ASPNET user?  Sounds like it may be running it under a different user.

Comment: I have set everything in the Security tab to full control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. I needed to have the filename in the SaveLocation. Completely missed that.

Comment: Just post that info in the original question, not as an answer.

Comment: @Jack - Actually he was providing an answer to his own question, which is both valid for the stack overflow platform and correct for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IIS are you using?

On IIS 6 and higher it is NETWORK SERVICE.

On IIS 5 and below it is the ASPNET user account that needs the required access.

Comment: I'm using the built-in Cassini web server. But I did give NETWORK SERVICE and ASPNET access, full access.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IIS, find out what system (or user) account for the application pool for the site you are having issues with.  Check to make sure that that user has permissions to the folder in question.

If you're in Visual Studio 2005+, it is rolling up a new ASP.NET Development Server.  This runs as your currently logged-in account.  Are you a local admin on this machine?

Comment: I'm using VS 2010, and I'm not the administrator. Although my user account has full control.

Comment: Have you tried enabling Full Control to Everyone?  If this causes the error to go away, then there's an account permissions issue.  If the error still exists, then you have a different directory access issue.